# iOS frame and dimensions

Tags: ios

I've searched a lot but find nothing about frame and dimension. I thought this should be a big topic.

Anyway, when create a view using frame, the whole screen size is 320*460 (320*480), but the dimensions of screen is 720*960. Can someone explain this? How to convert them.

This is only for 3.5 inch non-retina device.

EDIT:
I figured it out. The problem is because the size of iPad and iPhone is different. For iPhone, the dimension is 4:3, but for iPad, the dimension is 1.33.

Comment: From where you got the value _720x960_?

Comment: @iMartin  After take picker from uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: So you are talking about photos, right? Do you understand, that _camera resolution_ **is not** _screen resolution_?

Answer (score 0):

Check out:
http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

Points are how the screen is measured by apps so if you place something at a position you place it at a point. There are two pixels per point on retina devices.

Answer (score 0):

> This is only for 3.5 inch non-retina device.

No, this is the point. 3.5 inch retina devices have a resolution of 640*960.

For development Apple convert this resolution to the old 320*480 dimensions. Why ? To develop the same way for retina and non-retina devices. Except that you have to provide retina image. For a classic 100x100 image named myImage.png you have to provide a 200x200 image named myImage@2x.png. But all the development except that is the same. There are 4 times more pixels per point (ppp) on retina devices than on old iOS devices but it's transparent for the developers.

For the 320*480 vs 320*460 point : this is the status bar. In iOS < 7.0 status bar took 20 pixels height. You always should trust the [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size to get the application size within the phone.

Update : you talk about uiimagepickercontroller don't mistake pictures taken from the camera (or from the web) with the screen resolution !

Comment: There is nothing about device resolution. Cuz I thought the image size from camera should be the same as screen size. Actually it's not.